# Creating a looping array inside Zapier Script editor

Tags: javascript, zapier

Hello need help adding this javascript to my private app in the Zapier developer online portal. Ideally this will be done in the script editor

```js
arrayName = ["element0", "element1", "element2", "element4"];
for (var x =0; i < arrayName.length, x++) {
    //Insert the code for your action
    console.log(arrayName[x]);
}
```

Comment: Which medium are you using? 1. Web Builder OR 2. CLI

Comment: Im using the Web builder

Comment: it'll go in one of the methods described [here](https://zapier.com/developer/documentation/v2/scripting/#available-methods), depending on when you want it to run. Side note, there's probably a typo in the second part of your `for` loop declaration. You probably want to use `x`, not `i`.